# Use Java with Airflow and Docker

Tags: java, docker, airflow

I have a use case where I want to run a jar file via Airflow, all of which has to live in a Docker Container on Mac.

I have tried installing java separately and also, tried mounting my JAVA_HOME(host) onto the container.

This is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
airflow:
    image: 'puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9'
    hostname: airflow
    container_name: airflow
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ${JAVA_HOME}:/usr/local/bin/java //FWD MOUNTING JAVA_HOME
```

This way, I get a java directory inside /usr/local/bin/ with the data but `java -version` returns `Permission denied`.
Changing it to `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java:/usr/local/bin/java` returns `exec format error`.

What is the correct way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're getting `Permission denied` because you are running docker with user `airflow`.

Can you try to run it as `root`? (this is risky! don't use in production - it is just an effort to temporary workaround). Avoid using `root` user!

```
airflow:
    image: 'puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9'
    hostname: airflow
    container_name: airflow
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ${JAVA_HOME}:/usr/local/bin/java
```

**EDIT**:
Instead of mounting your local java, consider installation of a seperate one:

```
airflow:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: airflow
    container_name: airflow
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
```

and add the `Dockerfile` in the same directory:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jdk && apt-get clean
USER airflow
```

Comment: This doesn't work. JAVA_HOME is not the link of executable in my system. JAVA_HOME->bin->java is the executable on the host system too.

Comment: @proprius you can either mount the executable file or install java within the image. I've edit the answer above

Comment: And like, 99% of the time, the idea "run as root" is the wrong approach. Remember that thousands of people might read your answer in the future. Be really careful about putting "run as root" anywhere.

Comment: @GhostCat true. I assume he is doing POC, cause most of the people won't mount their java too. I suggested another solution - installing java within the container. Anyway - I'll clarify the `root` issue in my answer - thanks!

Comment: I figured why was the mounting not working. I am using MacOS which is why Java installed on my machine was different from the one which was required by Docker(which uses Debian on OSX host).

Comment: @ItayB thanks for the solution. It would work for other systems but there is apparently a bug with Debian Docker systems. There is an additional line to run before installing `jdk`, that makes it functional `RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1`

Comment: @proprius thanks! I've updated my answer for others. I'll appreciate it if you accept the answer :)